# Получение элемента из кортежа MultiIndex DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Изучаю вопрос, можно ли получить конкретный элемент из кортежа MultiIndex.

Имею DataFrame с построенным MultiIndex:

```
test = {'UID' : ('00000639616', '00000675306', '00000675305','00000639617', '00000675301', '00000675302'),
          'ID': ('02ab9161', '02ab9162', '02ab9163','02ab9164', '02ab9165', '02ab9166 '),
        'АНДС': (True, True, True, False, True, False),
        'Дата': ('2019-01-01', '2020-01-01', '2021-01-01','2019-01-01', '2020-01-01', '2021-01-01'),
'Бизнес-Линия': ('Сегмент1', 'Сегмент1', 'Сегмент1', 'Сегмент1', 'Сегмент1','Сегмент1')}

df_test = pd.DataFrame(test)
df_test.set_index(['ID', 'АНДС', 'Дата'], inplace=True)
df_test.sort_index(ascending=True, inplace=True)
```

Выглядит DataFrame так:

```
                                    Расчет          Бизнес-Линия
ID        АНДС     Дата
02ab9161  True     2019-01-01       00000639617     Сегмент1
02ab9162  True     2020-01-01       00000675306     Сегмент1
02ab9163  True     2021-01-01       00000675306     Сегмент1
02ab9164  False    2019-01-01       00000639617     Сегмент1
02ab9165  True     2020-01-01       00000675306     Сегмент1
02ab9166  False    2021-01-01       00000675306     Сегмент1
```

Cлучайным образом выбираю одну строку:

```
example = df_test.sample(1)
```

Получаю образец (example) со следующим индексом:

```
ID        АНДС     Дата             Расчет          Бизнес-Линия
02ab9161  True     2019-01-01       00000639617     Сегмент1

MultiIndex([('02ab9161', True, '2019-01-01')],
           names=['ID', 'АНДС', 'Дата'])
```

> #### Задача:
>
> Определить `id_client` из полученного example: `'02ab9161'`

Решаю так:

```
idclient=example.index[0][0]
```

Недостаток такого подхода в жесткой привязке к положению. Исследую вопрос, можно ли сделать как-то так:

```
idclient=example.index['ID']
```

То есть, получить конкретный элемент индекс по названию столбца, а не по слайсу элемента.

Comment: Пока дошел только до такого "способа": id_client = pd.DataFrame(example).reset_index()['ID'][0]

Comment: Таким способом я проблему решаю, но время исполнения... 1.78 ms... Против 8.27 µs при прямом обращении

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
In [13]: example
Out[13]:
                                    UID Бизнес-Линия
ID        АНДС  Дата
02ab9166  False 2021-01-01  00000675302     Сегмент1

In [14]: id_client = example.index.get_level_values("ID")[0]

In [15]: id_client
Out[15]: '02ab9166 '
```

Answer (score 1):

Остановился на варианте:

```
id_client = pd.DataFrame(example).reset_index()['ID'][0]
```